# Binomial trial, example

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

I have a rather standard problem. Suppose that 10 unfair coins are tossed.
What is the probability of obtaining 4 successes (H) where the probability
of success (H) is 6/7 and failure (T) is 1/7?
I'm looking for a symbolic formula involving binomial coefficients.

Comment: Then what exactly *is* the problem? Are you not familiar with [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) yet? Then have a look at the link. Btw, *one* unfair coin tossed $10$ times is enough, because apparantly the probability on success is not varying per coin.

Comment: I cannot put correctly together the symbolic expression which is finally divided by $2^{10}$. Yes, of course 1 coin is enough. I wish to compare what I have with what is the correct answer. Can you produce one?

Comment: Dividing by $2^{10}$ only has relevance if the coin is fair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the coin would be fair then the answer would be:$$\binom{10}4\left(\frac12\right)^4\left(\frac12\right)^6=2^{-10}\binom{10}4$$

This corresponds with the fact that $$\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}k1^k1^{10-k}=\left(1+1\right)^{10}=2^{10}$$

In this case the answer is $$\binom{10}4\left(\frac67\right)^4\left(\frac17\right)^6=7^{-10}\binom{10}46^4$$

This corresponds with the fact that $$\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}k6^k1^{10-k}=\left(6+1\right)^{10}=7^{10}$$

Maybe this makes things clear.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $$\binom {10} {4} (6/7)^4 (1/7)^6$$

Comment: Yes. My solution is the same, but I have also divided by $2^{10}$ at the end. Is it wrong? Thank you.

Comment: @user122424  Do not divide by $ 2^{10}$.  That makes it wrong.